# Generate definition for other JS "compilers" from TypeScript definition file?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, typescript

Given a TypeScript definition file, is there any (automated/quick/easy) way to "convert" this definition so it will work with other JavaScript compilers?

I realize there are a ton of "JavaScript compilers" out there, but the goal is to determine which are the most popular and be able to provide definition files for those frameworks.

Comment: Write a parser, lexer, and compiler that compiles to your target, I guess.

Comment: Are you asking if a "broader" definition format exists that TypeScript definitions can be converted to, so that it can be used in not only TypeScript itself, but other compilers / transpilers?

Comment: Not necessarily, multiple "definition files" would be the goal - one for FrameworkX, one for FrameworkY, etc. to provide design-time intellisense as supported in a developer's given IDE and their chosen JS compiler/framework.

Comment: @JoshM. Do you mean that the awesome TypeScript interfaces system would be implemented everywhere else? Where?

Comment: @Tarh - I sense sarcasm but I'm not sure I follow...I'm not suggesting that all frameworks should "understand" a TypeScript definition.

Comment: I'm not sure this would help at all - but there is a TypeScript definition to Haxe converter (https://github.com/Simn/ts2hx), which in turn might help you create externs / definitions on other platforms (maybe?). Just speculating at this point though, but thought it could be useful.

Comment: Please define "JavaScript compilers". There's a ton of languages that compile to JavaScript listed in Jeremy Ashkenas's GitHub repository. But they are different languages with different (if any) language bindings to 3rd party libraries. Please provide some 2 or 3 **concrete examples** of what you want

Answer (score 1):

> is there any (automated/quick/easy) way to "convert" this definition so it will work with other JavaScript compilers

No. And considering the still active development in the TypeScript land it would be a non trivial task to have such a thing without active maintainence. Consider the simple case of `union` types (e.g `string | number`) which was unsupported by some custom TypeScript parsers for a few months.

Now the moving target is ES6 module syntax support

Soon : others https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap

You would have to pick *one* other Compile to JS language that also has TypeSafety (that rules out coffeescript) and start hacking away at it.